# If statement is not displaying the elements in div in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

This is my html component file and here is have used *ngIf at one div and enabled trigger on click of a button but even the value turns to be true the div is not getting enabled

```
 <section id="contact">
      <div class="section-content">
        <h1 class="section-header">Welcome to our <span class="content-header wow fadeIn " data-wow-delay="0.2s"
            data-wow-duration="2s"> Service Request Form</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-section">
        <div class="container">
          <form>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="test">
                <label for="exampleInputUsername">InvoiceId(Mandatory)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="test"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit" (click)="checkdeatils($event)"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"
                    aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Product Details</button></div>
            </div>
    
            <div *ngIf="isValid">
              <div class="col-md-6 form-line">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputUsername">Your name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

ts file:-

```
  isValid = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  checkdeatils(event) {
    this.isValid = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: The variable name in html is `isValid` and in the ts file is `isvalid`. Since variable names are case sensitive, change either one of them to have same names.

Comment: What happens when you put {{ isValid | json }} in the html just before the div with the if?

Comment: are you using change detection OnPush strategy? if that is the case you have trigger change detection manually

Answer (score -1):

There is type mistake use  ***ngIf="isvalid==true"** instead of  *ngIf="isValid" in .cshtml

Comment: assign isvalid:boolean; and in constructor(){this.isvalid=false;}